# php ActiveRecord and json_encode æøå encoding issue

Tags: php, encoding, special-characters, json, phpactiverecord

Now I, in my own opionion, have tried everything there is on this encoding problem, looked through a lot of answered quistions but nothing worked for me, so here I go.

I have a MySQL database with a `Users` table. This table has a column for "firstname" which collation is set to `utf8_general_ci` (all varchar columns is). I have then inserted a row where the firstname-column is set to "Løw", with the scandinavian special character "ø".

I now use the php-ActiveRecord library, where the connection string is to ";charset=utf8", to retrieve the row and afterwards outputs the user as json, like so:

```
$user = User::find($ID);
$userArr = $user->to_array();
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
print(json_encode($userArr));
```

Now the wired things starts. The firstname is now NOT "Løw" as displayed in the MySQL Database , but **"L\u00f8w"**. I then tried to see if this was also the case without the `json_encode` function, like so:

```
$user = User::find($ID);
$userArr = $user->to_array();
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
print_r($userArr);
```

But here the output was correct, firstname was "Løw". I then tried to encode the fields in the array to `utf-8`, since everybody told me if the strings was `utf-8` it should work, like so:

```
$return[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $userArr);
print_r(json_encode($return));
```

But this gave me **"L\u00c3\u00b8w"**, so that didn't work. I then tried, since i was out of ideas to utf8_decode it:

```
$return[] = array_map('utf8_decode', $userArr);
print_r(json_encode($return));
```

But that made the string return as **"null"**. I then tried to check what encoding my vars was when they came out of the database, like so:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
print(mb_detect_encoding($userArr['firstname']));
```

But this returned `UTF-8`.

So as you, hopefully, can see, i have tried everything and i still don't know why my `json_encode`, changes the "ø" charcter to **"\u00f8"**. Please help, i don't want to make my own json_encode-method.

Comment: The json_encoded string "L\u00f8w" should be correctly displayed as "Löw" in a HTML-page if you take the JSON-data and put it in for example a `div` in the client. Have you tried using the json_encoded data in a HTML-page?

Comment: no, but i dont see the point since its a REST server i am trying to build that don't return HTML but JSON. But found one answer described in the first answer :)

Comment: I think the escaped character will be understood correctly by an application, for example a webb-application using HTML to display views.

Comment: Thats true, thanks. I will keep that in mind when i try it on the application, now I at least know how to fix it if it fails :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found an answer pretty quick, but ill let other scandinavian people know, since i coulden't find anything on the subject.

I solved the problem by adding the following to the json_encode method:

```
print(json_encode($userArr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

This tells the method NOT to escape unicode chars (i think) or as it says in the PHP doc:

> JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE (integer)
>
> Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as
>   \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.